# Adding two large double numbers in C gives an incorrect result

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I would like to ask you a question regarding to adding two big numbers that are double in the C language.

Lets say there are two numbers that are double: 1.31E+42 and 1.399E+43.

If I do the adding in Excel, the result is 15300000000000000000000000000000000000000000. That should be correct.

If I do the adding in the C language, the result is 15299999999999999804719125983728080953278464.

The difference is quite huge. Does anybody know how to get the right result when adding or multiplying big numbers in the C language that are double?

I have to add another important information. One thing is to print it out. I know that it is possible to print the number as you guys suggested. But I also need it as the value for another work. To be specific, it is a task of analysing two circles - their intersection and/or touching (if they touch externally or internally or if there is an intersection).
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z9pssbk/revision/4
Two circles will touch if the distance between their centres (V) is equal to the sum of their radii (external touch), or the difference between their radii (internal touch). So I have to do the adding for external touch and then to compare if the distance between their centers V is the same like the sum of their radii. So it is not only about printing the value out.

First circle:

```
Sx = -3.2E+41, Sy = -3.31E+42, R = 1.31E+42
```

Second circle:

```
Sx = 1.354E+43, Sy = 3.17E+42, R = 1.399E+43
```

The distance between their centers in C language is:

```
V = 15300000000000002280599204554488630751526912.000000
```

Sum of their radii is in the C language:

```
SumR =15299999999999999804719125983728080953278464.000000
```

According to the reference they should touch externally, so if I do the following condition I get the information that there is no external touch.

```
if (fabs(V - SumR) < 0.001)
  printf("There is an external touch")
else
  printf("No external touch")
```

Comment: The result is not “1.53E+43” in Excel. That is just what it shows you with default formatting. The actual result is different, likely the same as you are getting with C.

Comment: try [`printf("delta %f\n", 15300000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - 15299999999999999804719125983728080953278464);`](https://ideone.com/3a4Zkj)

Comment: I dispute that the difference is "huge". It differs at the 18th digit, which is all that `double` is good for. If you output more decimals, would that be more huge? In the days of slide rules, all we got was 3 digits, perhaps 4 or 5 on an extra long (cylinder) slide rule. But as engineers, we would multiply that by 3 anyway, for safety.

Comment: @WeatherVane For fun: a [paper slide rule](https://www.instructables.com/Make-a-simple-paper-slide-rule/)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica neat! I still have a 12" slide rule and a cylindrical one but I can't find the log tables. I could make a set with a C program though if I ever need them.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point arithmetic approximates real-number arithmetic. When converting decimal numbers to binary floating-point or doing floating-point arithmetic, you generally should not expect the results you would get with real-number arithmetic.

This answer assumes your C implementation uses the IEEE-754 binary64 format for `double` and performs arithmetic using round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, including conversion from decimal to `double`.

The binary64 format has a sign, a 53-bit significand (a “fraction portion” of the number), and an 11-bit exponent.

This format cannot represent 1.31•10<sup>42</sup>. The nearest value it can represent is 1310000000000000060347708657386176332693504. When your C source text contains `1.31e42`, your compiler converts it to 1310000000000000060347708657386176332693504. If we write this using hexadecimal for the significand, it is 1.E137CED6DF0D1<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>139</sup>. You can see the initial “1” and 13 more hexadecimal digits (4 bits each) make up 53 bits.

The format also cannot represent 1.399•10<sup>43</sup>. The nearest value it can represent is 13989999999999999899113922237014438982975488. When your C source text contains `1.399e43`, your compiler converts it to 13989999999999999899113922237014438982975488. Using hexadecimal, this is 1.4131D470653E9<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>143</sup>

When these are added, the ordinary mathematical result is not representable. The result produced is the nearest representable number, which is 15299999999999999804719125983728080953278464. Using hexadecimal, this is 1.5F45515DD32F6<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>143</sup>.

This is the right result as expected for floating-point arithmetic. Getting the “right” result for your purpose depends on what you want to accomplish. For many purposes, getting an approximate result with floating-point suffices, and one simply understands that the result is approximate. If an exact result is necessary, alternative formats and software must be used.

Comment: I would add that the excell has very limited precision and strange rounding algorithms `15299999999999900000000000000000000000000000.00` if you enter a number from the OP question

Answer (score 2):

If you need to process big numbers, you should use an [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (a.k.a bignums) library, such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).

If you want to use floating point numbers, take time to understand them by reading the [floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) and about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). They don't follow intuitive properties of [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) (e.g. most operations are not associative).

Read of course [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website, then the C11 draft standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).